# IE pushes content over with CSS list

Tags: css

I have code for a hover drop-down nav bar that I found online.
It should drop down a sub menu when you hover the mouse over the main text.

In Chrome and FF it's perfect but in IE(8) it pushes the ul code over to the right, making it impossible to move the cursor to.

Thanks.

CSS:

```
#dropmenu,
#dropmenu ul {
list-style: none;
}
#dropmenu {
float: left;
width: auto;
}

#dropmenu li {
width: auto;
}

#dropmenu > li {
float: left;
width: auto;    
}
#dropmenu li a {
display: block;
height: 2em;
line-height: 2em;
padding: 0 1.5em;
text-decoration: none;
}
#dropmenu ul {
position: absolute;
display: none;
z-index: 999;
}
#dropmenu ul li a {
width: 80px;
}
#dropmenu li:hover ul {
display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="dropmenu">
<li><a href="#">Our Company</a>
<ul>
        <li><a href="#">Hellenico</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Genere</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Indulgentia</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
<li><a href="#">Our Solutions</a>
<ul>
        <li><a href="#">Hellenico</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Genere</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Indulgentia</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
<li><a href="#">Service Desk</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Hellenico</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Genere</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Indulgentia</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">resources</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Hellenico</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Genere</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Indulgentia</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a>
<ul>
        <li><a href="#">Hellenico</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Genere</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Indulgentia</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: "*I need to get it fixed as soon as possible.*" ... You should really rephrase your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the ending `</ul>` for your list with `id="dropmenu"`. That could be a problem, Chrome and Firefox are better at helping to complete broken code, whereas IE tends to break.

You do not end the  that wraps the entire menu. At the very end of your html you should add

```
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you expand on that please? I think I understand what you mean, just having trouble locating it